# $request-merge() disappears in parent controller

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm stuck on a weird issue...

I have a simple middleware.

```
$request->merge([
   'user' => $jwt->toArray(),
   'app_version' => $request->header('app-version')
]);
```

When I do a dump right before the `$next($request);` the it has the user object and the app_version. All good! See image below:

[image]

Moving to the controller. When in the function of defined in the route, and doing a `dump($request);` it has the user Object

[image]

The InstallController extends the controller.php which extends the `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

In the controller.php we have a construct function.

[image]

For some reason here the `$request` is empty and lost the object.

[image]

Why is this happening? And why is this available in the InstallController but not in the parent?

Comment: are you expecting the `user` input to be in the query string?

Comment: Nope, that is the weirdest part... $request->merge() puts its there.

Comment: I would be using `$request->input(...)` but other than that the controller is constructed before the request passes through the middleware stack

Comment: Better if you should post it as text. Not as an image.

Comment: Does `$request->user()` gives something (check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication) page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What turned out is the following. In Laravel lumen, controller constructors are called after the middleware has completed the request. In Laravel the constructors are called before the middleware.

Meaning that adding params to the request in the middleware in Laravel doesn't work.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.